# Deploy a spring boot Application in an Existing Tomcat Server

Tags: tomcat, servlets, spring-boot

Is three a way to deploy a Spring boot Application into a tomcat server which is already running a servlet application

Comment: Have you taken the time to read the [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html#howto-traditional-deployment)? This has a whole chapter on that.

Comment: Yeah , but what I need is to run the spring boot application as jar file, not a WAR file

Comment: You cannot. You deploy a war file not a jar file.